# How do to connect a model & controller to button in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing Ruby On Rails, which works fine (I inherited it).

I need to add some functionality to the application and I built a model and controller and I want a button press to route to the controller.

I figure I need to do something like:
    <%= form_tag(url_for(:controller => "do_something", :action => "sup"), ...

I have a controller that looks like:
    class DoSomething < ApplicationController
       ...
    end

How do I tell the framework that pushing that button fires the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't fire a controller; you fire an action within that controller.

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def panic
    # some code here
  end
end
```

Then in your `config/routes.rb`, have a route that points to that action:

```
match '/something/panic' => 'something#panic', :as => 'panic_button'
```

Then in your view file,

```
button_to 'press me in emergency', panic_button_path
```

or

```
button_to 'press me in emergency', '/something/panic'
```